# React Navigation Material Bottom Tabs on press effect has a square border

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a problem with changing the ripple effect border in React Navigation Material Bottom Tabs. My ripple effect has a square border.

[image]

But I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

My code is for now very similar to the last example on [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator).

Comment: The example's snack is working fine (with a circle ripple). Could you provide your code and a reproducible [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/)?

Comment: I just copied their code and pasted inside my project. I didn't make any changes. I know the example's snack is working fine but if I copy the same code inside my project I didn't get the same effect. I also copied their dependencies. Nothing works. But I managed to achieve the effect. I just used Material Top Tabs and change their position to bottom.